# Node.js optimization with constants

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization

Please compare:

```
// Version 1
    const oneHour = 60 * 60
    function checkTime(timePast) {
        if (timePast<7 * 24 * oneHour) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

// Version 2
    const oneHour = 60 * 60
    const oneWeek = 7 * 24 * oneHour
    function checkTime(timePast) {
        if (timePast<oneWeek) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

During millions of calls to checkTime(), is version 2 faster than version 1, or is Node.js smart enough to make the extra calculation in version 1 only once?

Comment: [almost no difference at all](https://jsperf.com/checktime-optimization/1)

Comment: This should be taken care of by constant-folding and inlining.

Comment: Sirko, so you are saying that the compiler takes care of it, i.e. the two versions are equally fast?

Answer (score 2):

According to this article: [Node.js Under The Hood #10 - Compiler Optimizations!](https://dev.to/khaosdoctor/node-js-under-the-hood-10-compiler-optimizations-5dol) Node's compiler will perform Constant Folding optimization, such that `const j = 3 + 9` will become `const j = 12`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check it like this:

```
    const oneHour = 60 * 60
    const oneWeek = 7 * 24 * oneHour;
    const randomData = generateArray();
    
    function generateArray () {
        let arr = [];

        for(i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
        }

        return arr;
    }

    function checkTime1(timePast) {
        if (timePast<7 * 24 * oneHour) {
            Math.random()
        }
    }

    function checkTime2(timePast) {
        if (timePast<oneWeek) {
            Math.random()
        }
    }

    console.time('checkTime1');
    randomData.forEach(i => checkTime1(i))
    console.timeEnd('checkTime1');

    console.time('checkTime2');
    randomData.forEach(i => checkTime2(i))
    console.timeEnd('checkTime2');
```

After several checks change order of "checkTime2" and "checkTime1", to be sure the result is valid. Seems Node.js is smart enough to make the extra calculation.

Comment: I appreciate your answer (upvoted), but I am hoping someone can answer my question a bit more conceptually/theoretically.